# Query records which a have multiple conditions and records on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails app which have a people table and an availabilities table:

Person.rb

```
has_many :availabilities
```

Availability.rb

```
belongs_to :person
```

People columns are irrelevant here. Availabilities have three particulars columns I use to find available people:

```
day: integer #0-6 0 is sunday
start_time: time
end_time: time
```

Actually there's a search engine that give the ability to do queries like this:

```
people = people.joins("INNER JOIN availabilities ON availabilities.person_id = people.id")
people = people.where("availabilities.day = ?", params[:day])

....
```

So, for instance, we can search for some people available on sunday from 8am to 11am.

I would like to implement a multi-day search. The search engine would display a multi select field and return an array of integer we can use:

```
params[:day] = ["1","2","3"]
```

A typical query would be: who are the people that have availabilities monday, friday and sunday from 8am to 12 pm. And we expect a list of people which have all those three day of availabilities,

My question is how to build the query? Is there an active record way or should I use plain SQL? The database is Postgres.

I can't use `IN` with `HAVING/COUNT` because a person can have multiple availabilities the same day.

My first guest is to try a generic union/intersect query builder but maybe I missing something easier.

I already search but maybe I missed something, any info is welcome!

ps: If you have a better idea for the title of my question, I struggle to find one.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a SQL fragment:

```
people = people.where("availabilities.day = ?", params[:day])
```

What you're looking for is the SQL IN operator, then you can pass in an Array:

```
people = people.where("availabilities.day IN ?", params[:day])
```

I'd put all of that in a scope on Availability with `.includes` to do the join:

```
def self.find_people(days)
  # attach a list of people to each day
  includes(:people).where("day IN ?", days)
end
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I can't use `IN` because as mentioned I need to pick people with all the selected days and not just one of them. Using `IN` with `HAVING/COUNT` is also not possible because you can have more than one availability the same day. That's why I was looking into raw sql query maybe with `INTERSECT` to build the query from smaller one (one by day for instance).

Comment: I edited my question, maybe it wasn't obvious that this solution will not work here. But thank you for your answer btw.